# Writing a Python Created Pivot Table using Pandas to a Excel Document

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, openpyxl

I have been working on automating a series of reports in python. I have been trying to create a series of pivot tables from an imported csv (binlift.csv). I have found the Pandas library very useful for this however, I cant seem to find anything that helps me write the Panda created pivot tables to my excel document (Template.xlsx) and was wondering if anyone can help. So far I have the written  the following code

```
import openpyxl
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


file1 = "Template.xlsx"   # template file
file2 = "binlift.csv"     # raw data csv


wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file1) # opens template
ws1 = wb1.create_sheet("Raw Data") # create a new sheet in template called Raw Data


summary = wb1.worksheets[0]    # variables given to sheets for manipulation
rawdata = wb1.worksheets[1]



headings = ["READER","BEATID","LIFTYEAR","LIFTMONTH","LIFTWEEK","LIFTDAY","TAGGED","UNTAGGEDLIFT","LIFT"]
df = pd.read_csv(file2, names=headings)

pivot_1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["LIFTYEAR", "LIFTMONTH","LIFTWEEK"], values=["TAGGED","UNTAGGEDLIFT","LIFT"],aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot_2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["LIFTYEAR", "LIFTMONTH"], values=["TAGGED","UNTAGGEDLIFT"],aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot_3 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["READER"], values=["TAGGED","UNTAGGEDLIFT","LIFT"],aggfunc=np.sum)

print(pivot_1)
print(pivot_2)
print(pivot_3)

wb1.save('test.xlsx')enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in pandas to write the 'xlsx' files.
Here basically we get all the indices (at level 0) of the pivot table, and then one by one we go over these indices to subset the table and write that part of the table.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

for manager in pivot_1.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    temp_df = pivot_1.xs(manager, level=0)
    temp_df.to_excel(writer, manager)

writer.save()
```

Comment: That's great, this code creates a new excel workbook. Is there anyway that I can append the pivot table to an existing worksheet(Template.xlsx). More specifically at a specific cell range?